# How can I get the value of left top and right bottom point value of current window?

Tags: window, point, window-point

How can I get the value of left top and right bottom point value of current working window(the window currently focusing on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in chapter [The Window Start and End Positions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Start-and-End.html#Window-Start-and-End) of the elisp manual.  Specifically:

> -- Function: window-start &optional window
>        This function returns the display-start position of window WINDOW.
>        If WINDOW is ‘nil’, the selected window is used.
>
> -- Function: window-end &optional window update
>        This function returns the position where display of its buffer ends
>        in WINDOW.  The default for WINDOW is the selected window.

Be sure to read the whole manual section for details.